# How do I show selected log level?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently making a select box to show all the log messages, and I'm struggling with getting it to show all the log messages for the selected value. I can get the log messages for the individual values, so when you select "Info" it shows all the messages under "Info" level

However my question is how do I select a log level higher to show that log level and the log levels below that level?

**How I want it to work:**

Log messages come from my database, these are for application message logging for support useage

- "Debug" then have it select "Debug, Error, Message, Info"
- "Error" then have it select "Error, Message, Info"
- "Message" then have it select "Message, Info"
- "Info" then have it select "Info"

**Javascript Code**

```
FilterLoggingTable();


function FilterLoggingTable()
{

    // Check the value from the select box and filter out table data based on value selected
    if ($("#loggingInputs").val() != null || $("#loggingDatePicker").val() != null)
    {
        var searchLoggingText = document.getElementById("loggingInputs").value.trim();

        if (document.getElementById("loggingDatePicker") != null)
        {
            var searchLoggingDate = document.getElementById("loggingDatePicker").value.trim();
        }
    }

    if (typeof GetServerLogging == 'function')
    {
        GetServerLogging(searchLoggingText, searchLoggingDate);
    }

    // Calls search logging function 2.5 seconds after page is ready
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $("tr:not(:has(>th))").show().filter(function ()
        {
            var tableRowElement = this;
            var tableRowTextFound, dateSelectedFound;

            tableRowTextFound = (tableRowElement.textContent || tableRowElement.innerText || '').indexOf((searchLoggingText || "")) == -1;
            dateSelectedFound = (tableRowElement.textContent || tableRowElement.innerText || '').indexOf((searchLoggingDate || "")) == -1;

            return (tableRowTextFound || dateSelectedFound);
        }).hide();
    }, 1000);
};


// Get all server logging, and append to logging table (Logging page)
function GetServerLogging(loggingLevel, loggingDate) {


    $.post("php/getServerLogging.php", {
        command: "GetServerLogging",
        getServerLoggingLevel: loggingLevel,
        getServerLoggingDate: loggingDate
    })

    .success(function(data) {

        var jsonMessage = JSON.parse(data);

        var dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable(); 
        dataTable.rows().remove().draw();

        // Check to see if response message returns back "OK"
        if (jsonMessage.RESPONSE == 'OK') {



            $('#dataTables-example td').remove();
            $("#dataTables-example tr:empty").remove();

            // Set time before records start to load on page
            setTimeout(function() {  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                // Loops through the returned records
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonMessage.RECORDS.length; i++) {

                    var currentRecord = jsonMessage.RECORDS[i];
                    var selectRecord = JSON.stringify(currentRecord);

                    var serverLoggingTableBody = $('#dataTables-example').children('tbody');
                    var serverLoggingTable = serverLoggingTableBody.length ? serverLoggingTableBody : $('#dataTables-example');

                    // Check to see if server log text doesn't equal to "Successfully synchronised" 
                    if (currentRecord['ServerLogText'] != "Successfully synchronised") {

                        dataTable.row.add( [
                            GetCurrentDateUKFormatFromSQL(currentRecord['ServerLogDateTime']['date']),
                            currentRecord['ServerLogLevel'],
                            currentRecord['ServerLogText']
                        ] ).draw();
                    }
                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    })

    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log("Unable to retrieve data from the server");
    });
}
```

**PHP Code**

```
if (isset($_POST['getServerLoggingLevel']) && isset($_POST['command']) && $_POST['command'] == "GetServerLogging") {

        // Set server logging level to a variable to be used in MSSQL query
        $getServerLog     = $_POST['getServerLoggingLevel'];

        // Set server logging data to a variable to be used in MSSQL query
        $getServerLogDate = $_POST['getServerLoggingDate'];

        // Create a string format for server logging date 
        $originalDate = $getServerLogDate;
        $newDate      = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));

        // Use logging information to query to database to get the correct data back
        $SyncServerFunctionList->RespondWithUnencryptedJSONMessage("OK", $SyncServerFunctionList->MSSQLExecuteSelectAndReturnResultArray($connection, "SELECT Logs.Origin as ServerLogUser, Logs.Text as ServerLogText, 
                                                                                                                                                            Logs.Type as ServerLogLevel, Logs.Timestamp as ServerLogDateTime from Logs
                                                                                                                                                            where Logs.Type like '$getServerLog' and CONVERT(varchar(10), Logs.Timestamp, 120) like '$newDate'
                                                                                                                                                            ORDER BY Timestamp ASC", "", "failed to select registered midwives"));

    }
```

Comment: @Epodax I've updated my question, I've tried it and can't seem to get it working. However I can get each Log level working individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need using SQL to select multiple value like

```
SELECT *****
FROM recordtable
WHERE warninglevel IN("Error","warning" )
```

IN operator will let you select a field match multiple values. the example let you select logs for "Error" and "warning" level. You could do other selection like this.

Comment: wherby i'm not looking for console logs, i'm using log messages which I store into my database

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how the the tool is implemented. You could set a value for each level of message field : level.log=0 debug=1, info=2,warning=3,error=4. when you want to select the message from database, you could select all and then filter like  msgs.filter( msg.level> 2) which will only show warning and error. Or you could select each warning level from database.

Comment: could you be able to do an example in your answer?

Comment: @Chris see the answer modified above, is your scenario that: to process the log info in database according to the errorlevel?

Comment: I'm not writing the messages on the javascript/php side, i'm doing the error messages on client side which is written in objective-c. This is to show the messages on a Administrators Webpage for support purposes, the way it looks like you're saying is to get all the messages then write them back into the database with an error code. Which I don't want, I just want to get the messages from the database under the certain level. I've already got a Level such as "Debug", "Error", "Message" and "Info". I just need to know how to select the ones I want from the database when I need the information

Comment: Then why don't you using sql like :
SELECT *****
FROM table 
WHERE warninglevel  IN("Error","warning" ) // IN operator will let you select a field  match multiple values.